# Customized User and Graphical Interface for reports's website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, reporting-services, business-intelligence

If I have about 80 reports from SSRS that need to be applied to different website at SharePoint's intranet. Let's say about 20 for a webpage, 50 for a another webpage and 10 reports in a another webpage. I wonder if it possible to create a customized user and graphical website that shall contain reports being deployed from SSRS?

Comment: Well the short answer is 'Yes'. There's a Report Viewer see:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326362.aspx . You can also use the List viewer to provide a filter list of reports. What type of interface are you after?

Comment: The interface would be same as in report server but with more customization with additional functionality and new looks. I'm doing a prestudy about it.

Comment: Ok, what sort of customization and functionality are you after? Do you want user customization, eg. alerts? New looks would not be a problem if you used a web page and a list